# SetEnvIfNoCase Referer - for specific word only

Tags: php, .htaccess

There are several URLs that link to my site. I want to deny access to them.

All of these sites have a unique and common keyword in the URL: /roger23/

Example URLs are:

```
example.net/roger23/studie-ee.html
second-domain.org/roger23/somt-ohter-file.php
yetanotherone.eu/roger23/hello-world
```

etc.

So, again, the common keyword in all of these URLs is: /roger23/

I want to use .htaccess to deny access to such URL. Here is what I tried, but I need to make sure this is the correct way and it only covers links that contain "/roger23/" and nothing else (to prevent legitimate sites linking to the site).

So in htaccess I tried this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "/roger23/" spam=yes
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=spam
```

Is this the right way to do it? It seems to work but I don't want to exclude any other legitimate links that don't contain the word '/roger23/'.

For example, these ones should be allowed:

```
some-things.net/roger23
some-others2.com/roger23.html
```

I'm confused if there should be quotation marks there or maybe there should also be * or ^..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use such pattern to restrict access to urls with `/roger23/`:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^(.*)/roger23/(.*)" spam=yes
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=spam
```

Another solution for same problem of restricting access:

```
# Block visits from /roger23/
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)/roger23/(.*)$ [NC]
ReRewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Comment: it should work fine, but with using regex you can fine-tune your filter, also you can try to do the same through RewriteEngine